# What was the Marauder’s plan?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In the Solo Star Wars Story, during the train heist scene, the Marauders show up and make a play for the coaxium. Their speeder bikes don’t seem be capable of lifting the train car or going up against the seek & destroy droids, but nevertheless, there they are: blasting away at the cables attached to the only ship capable of making off with the loot. Only one marauder is sent onto the ship, who immediately attempts to kill the pilot of the ship sending it crashing out of control. It seems they were more concerned with just spoiling the heist than actually making off with the loot. Was there ANY cohesive plan on their end to actually obtain the coaxium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think their plan was just to destroy it and keep it out the hands of Crimson Dawn. If I remember correctly, I only seen the movie once, during the train scene, the leader of the Marauders simply starts to cut off the cables before the speeders are even latched to the container, maybe hoping it will just plunge in to bottom of the mountain. The speeders started to latch in to it after realizing the cargo ship was not taking out of commission, thanks to Han, so they were probably just trying to derail it at that point. At least that’s how I interpreted it.

Comment: The pilot Rio Durant states when the Marauders show up that "they're pirates trying to get the score out from under them." Given what we learn later about them it seems that they were more concerned with stopping Crimson Dawn than with getting the loot, however they did not actually actively try to destroy it until Han Solo improvised the plan and was taking off with the loot, that forced their hand. Before then the loot was firmly attached to the tracks and they were simply trying to destroy the ship. Goes without saying they had their own ship somewhere on the planet to carry the cargo.

Comment: I’m not sure it does go without saying... and if their goal was to simply keep it out of the hands of Crimson Dawn why bother? Why not just attack the heist team, or barring that, just destroy the train car itself?

Comment: Maybe their original plan was to take possession of the substance, but once they realized that was going to happen, they went with plan B... destroy it.

Comment: What do you mean @Celestialgranturismo that you're not sure? How do you think they're traveling from planet to planet if they don't have a way to travel from planet to planet? It is not in dispute that they have a ship, they load the cargo onto said ship at the end of the movie .I think you're just confused about this in general m8.

Comment: True.. I did not consider that obvious fact

Answer (score 3):

The 'marauders' started with seven speeder bikers. Three were destroyed and the remaining four bikes appear to be *just powerful enough* to lift the load with their harpoon cables but not to control it after it starts swinging out of control.

[image]

We can reasonably assume that with six or seven bikes (and fewer distractions) they would have had more than sufficient lifting capacity to take the train carriage *directly into the air* and airlift it to a nearby outcropping to unload the precious unobtanium before retreating to space in their spaceship.

> *The dangerous warrior ENFYS NEST suddenly appeared, flanked by a crew
> of Cloud-Riders on heavily modified speeders called swoops. **They
> wanted the coaxium, too!***
>
> ...
>
> *A train car full of coaxium was too big a score for Beckett to go down
> without a fight. He and Enfys battled on top of the train, **both trying
> to attach their own cables to the car to pull it away.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Solo: A Star Wars Story: Train Heist](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story:_Train_Heist)</sup></sub>